# Problems after submit form with new row added

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm having a little fight here, this is my problem: I have a table whose content is taken from a bean that contains 2 string variables and a list of beans which in turn are formed by 2 string variables and a MultipartFile. So, in this scenario I present to the user a table with like this:
[image: table populated with beans]

The problem comes when I try to implement the "Add image" functionality: a new row in the table is shown but after submit the values the bean that I receive in the controller put the new values into the last bean in the list, i.e. if in the new input for "Bean 2 - field 1" I put "**new_value_5**" in the controller I receive "**value 5, new_value_5**" into "field 1" of the last bean in the list, I don't receive a new instance of the bean, I just get all the values into the last bean of the list.
This is my code in the jsp page:

```
    <form:form action="myaction.html" method="post" modelAttribute="main_bean" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Bean 1 - field 1: <form:input path="bean1_field1"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bean 1 - field 2: <form:input path="bean1_field2"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Images:
                <table id="imgTable">
                    <tbody>
                    <c:forEach var="bean_2" items="${main_bean.list_of_bean_2}" varStatus="imgStatus">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="image/${main_bean.id}/${bean_2.pathImage}" class="imagen" width="100px;" height="100px;" id="idImage">
                                <div id="divFile" style="display:none;"><!-- When the user wants to add a new image I enable this input-->
                                    <form:input type="file" path="${bean_2.image}" name="imagen" id="imgFile"/>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Bean 2 - field 1: <form:input path="list_of_bean_2[${imgStatus.index}].field1" id="field1Id"/>
                                <form:input type="hidden" path="list_of_bean_2[${imgStatus.index}].id"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                Bean 2 - field 2: <form:input path="list_of_bean_2[${imgStatus.index}].field2" id="field2Id"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Add image" id="addImgBtn" class="addImgBtn">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Confirm changes" > </td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Cancel changes" > </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

And the structure of the beans:

```
public class Bean1 {
    private List<Bean2> imagesCampaign;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    //getters and setters
}

public class Bean2 {
    private MultipartFile image;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    //getters and setters
}
```

I didn't specified the code in the controller because I think is not necessary, but if you want it just let me know.
I will really appreciate if somebody could give me a clue about what's going on here. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I tried access to the n+1 index (`list_of_bean_2[${imgStatus.index + 1}]`) but got a `ConcurrentModificationException`
Anybody please a little help here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed myself to solve this problem, if someone knows a better solution I would be grateful but in the meantime here is my solution. Instead of having a button to do all the work I created 2: the first one will just add a row for the new image, and the second one will submit the data added, so, this is my javascript:

```
    $(".addImgBtn").click(function() {
        $('#imgTable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#imgTable tbody>tr:last');
        $("#imgTable tbody>tr:last #field1").val('');
        $("#imgTable tbody>tr:last #field2").val('');
        $("#imgTable tbody>tr:last #divFile").show();
        $(".addImgBtn").attr("disabled", "true");
        return false;
    });
```

The previous function will add a new row to the table, and it will disable the "Add image" button.

```
    $(".confirmImgBtn").click(function(eve) {
    var field1 = $("#imgTable tbody>tr:last #field1").val();
    var field2 = $("#imgTable tbody>tr:last #field2").val();
    var form = $('#confirmImgForm');
    var newfile = $("#imgTable tbody>tr:last #imgFile")[0].files[0];
    var formdata = false;
    if (window.FormData) {
        formdata = new FormData();
    }
    if ( window.FileReader ) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            //showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(newfile);
    }
    if (formdata) {
        formdata.append("image", newfile);
        formdata.append("field1",field1);
        formdata.append("field2",field2);
    }
    if (formdata) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                alert('succeed!!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The last function will submit the values to the controller: I read the values for the **field1**, **field2**, the **form** (just to get the url) and finally the **image**, and when I submit everything to the controller I receive an instance of my bean, which contains 2 string variables (for filed1 and field2) and a `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` for the image.